# Equations in Keynote in a browser

Tags: icloud, keynote

I am trying to see if I can add equations in Keynote in iCloud via browser (I don't have a Mac/Iphone). I searched but couldn't find a way other than copy-pasting an image from somewhere.
(I'm using Chrome, and I couldn't do it neither in Linux nor in Windows)

A similar question is about sub/super-scripts. I could not find a way to insert them either in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[This reference](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23115) may help.

For sub/superscripts, it says there is a keyboard shortcut for windows:  Control-Alt-Minus/Plus.

(Can't test this myself)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see this page. This does solve the sub/super script problem (I checked). The equations though I think are out of luck.